# IBM X3630m4 wont bootup with Vmware Esxi : New installation

Tags: vmware-esxi, ibm-xseries

We have an IBM server model X3630m4 and we are trying to install VMware ESXi 5.5 and above version but its not booting up after installation. The installation gets completed and asks us to reboot the server. But upon rebooting the server, the esxi wont boot up. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the hardware on the VMware HCL? - https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get you. Its a IBM rack server. The model number is X3630m4.

Comment: @user3824955: VMWare publishes a hardware compability list. Don't try to get it running on anything not on there, as it is not supported.

Comment: ESXi 5.5 is a bad choice for deployment as well, as it will be out of support in september.

Comment: I tried all version starting from latest to older version. None of them worked. They all get installed but wont boot after installation. I tried Citrix Xenserver also but no luck. Is there something to do with IBM hardware/firmware/BIOS?

Comment: Any error messages?  What's the (non) boot up behavior like?  I've had plenty of VMWare boot problems - a lot of times it is figuring out the way to do USB boot for that server.  Or the flip side could be true - do you have any extraneous USB devices plugged in while you are trying to boot to VMWare?

Comment: Also - what are you installing to?  USB / single hard drive on a standard controller / RAID array / NVMe PCIe SSD card / etc. ?